# Overrwrite the n-th byte in a binary(256)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I overwrite the n-th byte in a binary(256) using a stored procedure?
The procedure accepts two parameters:

```
@n tinyint -- index of byte
@value tinyint -- value to be written
```

I know that I can read a byte by using `substring` function, so I thought that I can write a byte using the `stuff` funtction, but it doesn't work.

I'n using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stuff`, but it returns a new value, not changes the value in-place.

```
set @pattern = stuff(@pattern, 5, 1, 0x80); -- changes 5th byte to 0x80
```